# OpenCV in Clojure AWS Lambda Function target is larger than 250MB, how do I reduce it's size?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, opencv, clojure, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use OpenCV https://opencv.org/ via [Origami](https://github.com/hellonico/origami) using [lein-lambda](https://github.com/paulbutcher/lein-lambda) to deploy. However my `target/` directory ends up being 350Mb while lambda requires the uncompressed upload to be max of 250Mb.

If I look at the contents of `target/`

```
$ tree -L 2 target/
target/
├── classes
│   ├── META-INF
│   ├── cheshire
│   ├── clj_time
│   ├── clojure
│   ├── clout
│   ├── compojure
│   ├── crypto
│   ├── detect-features
│   ├── detect_features
│   ├── instaparse
│   ├── medley
│   ├── opencv3
│   ├── ring
│   └── uswitch
├── clj-opencv-0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
├── clj-opencv-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
├── native
│   ├── linux
│   ├── macosx
│   └── windows
└── stale
    └── leiningen.core.classpath.extract-native-dependencies
```

I noticed that there are also OpenCV builds for `macosx` and `windows`. If I can remove those builds during the `lein lambda deploy production` command, then it should be small enough.

Here is my project.clj file, maybe it's realted to `uberjar`:

```
(defproject clj-opencv "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Identify key points and edges to use for good looking Delauney triangulation."
  :url "https://www.example.com/TODO"
  :min-lein-version "2.0.0"
  :injections [(clojure.lang.RT/loadLibrary org.opencv.core.Core/NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)]
  :test-paths ["test"]
  :resource-paths ["rsc"]
  :plugins [[lein-gorilla "0.4.0"]
            [lein-auto "0.1.3"]
            [lein-ring "0.9.7"]
            [lein-lambda "0.2.0"]]
  :auto {:default {:file-pattern #"\.(clj)$"}}
  :repositories [["vendredi" "https://repository.hellonico.info/repository/hellonico/"]]
  :aliases {"notebook" ["gorilla" ":ip" "0.0.0.0" ":port" "10000"]}
  :profiles {:dev {:resource-paths ["resources"]
                   :dependencies [; used for proto repl
                                  [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.11"]
                                  ; proto repl
                                  [proto-repl "0.3.1"]
                                  ; use to start a gorilla repl
                                  [gorilla-repl "0.4.0"]
                                  [seesaw "1.4.5"]
                                  ; aws lambda
                                  [javax.servlet/servlet-api "2.5"]
                                  [ring/ring-mock "0.3.1"]]}
             :uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.5"]
                 [origami "0.1.10"]
                 [compojure "1.6.0"]
                 [ring/ring-defaults "0.3.1"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [uswitch/lambda "0.1.2"]
                 [cheshire "5.7.1"]
                 [ring-apigw-lambda-proxy "0.3.0"]
                 [feedme "0.0.3"]
                 [clj-spotify "0.1.5"]
                 [rotary "0.4.1"]]
  :ring {:handler detect-features.handler/app}
  :lambda {:function {:name "lowpoly-detect-features" ; bucket name cannot contain underscores
                      :handler "detect-features.lambda.LambdaFn"}
           :api-gateway {:name "detect-features"}
           :stages {"production" {:warmup {:enable true}}
                    "staging"    {}}}
  ; For local runs. Probably needs to be off in projection.
  :main detect-features.lambda)
```

Comment: Are you sure about this? lein lambda should only need to upload the standalone jar, none of the other stuff in target. Looking briefly at its code, that seems to be what it does.

Answer (score 1):

Just use jar-exclusions:

```
:jar-exclusions [#"^docs/.*" #"^public/js/.*" #"^example-data/.*"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how `lein-lambda` works (if it uploads the jar or the uberjar - it should be your first focus), but I wanted to bring to your attention different approaches:

- https://github.com/portkey-cloud/portkey - which is fairly young but I think is trying to eliminate "dead" code
- [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard) which is used to [shrink code in android](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) - there is an example of using it in a `[boot][3]` task [there](https://github.com/alandipert/e2j/blob/master/build.boot#L42-L66)
- another alternative depending on your situation would be to use ClojureScript